# Remove subfolder from framework-generated URLs in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

My application lives in the subfolder `wwwroot/site1`, but I make it available at the root of the domain `www.mydomain.com` with a URL rewrite inbound rule.

This works great, but the problem is that ASP.NET MVC generates URLs **with** the `/site1` subfolder, since it does not know about the rewrite rule on the IIS level.

One way to fix that would be to create an outbound rule, but I think there must be a more elegant way. I'd prefer to handle it at the application level.

Is there a way to tell ASP.NET MVC to remove the `/dga` part from all generated URLs? In particular, the following URL writers:

```
Html.ActionLink(...)
Url.Action(...)

return RedirectToAction(...)
```

Of course I could just use an extension method like this:

```
public static string ReplaceSubfolder(this string str)  // and other types
{
    return str.Replace("/site1", "");
}

Html.ActionLink(...).ReplaceSubfolder()
Url.Action(...).ReplaceSubfolder()

return RedirectToAction(...).ReplaceSubfolder()
```

but this is even less elegant. I'm looking for a way to influence the routing that generates the URLs.

Comment: Could you please provide your `project.json` relevant parts? Thanks

Comment: @MaximeRouiller Sorry, it's currently an MVC 5.2 project without a `project.json` file. Do we need one to make this work?

Comment: Havn't looked too much into Asp.net 5, it is still only Preview I believe, had several issues. But I do know you can modify wwwroot to what ever you want it is in one of the new .json config files

Comment: @cheeesus No you don't. Your question was flagged "asp.net-mvc6" and it's a normal question for this framework. :)

Comment: @MarkHomer ASP.NET 5 has been rolled out on 17 October 2013, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework#Release_history)

Comment: @cheeesus I have vs2015 and ASP.net 5 templates are preview, I tried them and had several issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is very easy to do with IIS. Just create a separate Web Site for each domain, choose the subfolder where the application lives (for example `wwwroot/site1`), set up the bindings (HTTP and/or HTTPS) to listen to the domain you want. When the Web Site is created, `Convert to application..` the relevant folder, and everything should appear to be in the root of the domain.